# How to have C# connect to the excel API

Tags: c#, .net, excel, vba

Is it possible to connect to the same excel libraries that are used in VBA, but to instead use C# to be able to use all of the .Net framework features?  I would like to recreate some automated VBA applications in C# at some point in the near future on the .Net framework to expand upon their capabilities and increase their speeds but I'm not sure how to do this.

Comment: You can also use "Office Interop".

Comment: as I dont like VBA this sonds like a pretty cool Idea :) +1

Comment: [This](http://www.siddharthrout.com/2012/08/10/settingupdotnetwithexcel/) is how you do it for VB.Net which is same for C# as well :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can reference the .dll file directly which is referenced by default when using VBA.  It is called the "Microsoft excel object library", and you add it as a reference the same way you would do with any other namespace in C#

Here is a great reference to use http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5123/Opening-and-Navigating-Excel-with-C